# Visual Studio Code with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

[image]

Sorry if this is a basic question. My VSCode shows wavy line if I use type annotation. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: That looks a lot like Typescript, not Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type annotations are not part of ecmascript 6, it seems like you're using [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) syntax.

There are [extensions](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode) for Visual Studio Code to support this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Those wavy red lines are errors. 
You can either see what is the type of error in console